# Extend cache TTL for Angular bundles

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular9

My Angular v9 bundles appear to have a cache TTL (time to live) of 1 hour. Is there a way to extend that to a custom amount? I'm pretty sure the random characters that I represent below with asterisks means the build process is implementing cache busting, so I don't see any reason to have a short cache TTL. I can't seem to find any info on this anywhere.

Here are the bundles I'm referring to:

- main-es2015.***.js
- polyfills-es2015.***.js
- runtime-es2015.***.js
- styles.***.js

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Firebase. Is this something I will have to handle there?

Comment: Cache headers are set from the webserver for static files, so I'd say yes

Comment: This is what I needed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers